# Load PyTorch Model into ONNX (C++) and calculate gradients

Tags: pytorch, onnx, onnxruntime

Using `torch.export.onnx()` you can export a trained pytorch model to onnx and execute inference there. Now ONNX also provides the possibility to calculate gradients and i would like to use the `Ort::TrainingSession()` to perform a TrainStep and therewith calculate the gradient concerning the input. Is this possible with an external model?

Thanks

For this i would need a `Ort::CheckpointState` and for this an ONNX CheckpointState which i don't have since i only have an exported model.

I am already able to perform the model inference evaluation in onnx with a Ort::Session.

I tried to just enter the exported .onnx model but i got the Error:
'Ort::Exception'
Checkpoint folder does not exist.

Did someone already use this part of ONNX Training or knowns how to proceed?